# Invalid package family name error on Windows PhoneGap app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows, phonegap, appx

I have done a windows app using phoneGap, But when I upload the APPX file in windows dev center, I got some errors like 'Invalid package family name'. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I worked through a similar problem today and I found this article helpful:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html

Check your build configuration file (build.json) and make sure you select a release if your release settings are defined to match the Strong Name with the Windows Store expected Publisher Name.

If you are using Tools for Apache Cordova (TACO), you will also want to review your config.xml file both with the GUI and then with an raw XML editor like WordPad.

```
   <preference name="WindowsStoreDisplayName" value="XXX" />
   <preference name="WindowsStoreIdentityName" value="YYYXXX" />
   <vs:platformSpecificValues>
     <vs:platformSpecificWidget platformName="windows" id="_ZZZZZZZZ" />
   </vs:platformSpecificValues>
```

Where you fill in the value the Windows Store expects in the XXX, YYY and ZZZ fields.

Hope that helps,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

if you are using https://build.phonegap.com you need compile using cli-6.0.0