# Issue with publishing my windows app (phonegap) - invalid package identity name

Tags: windows, config, store, phonegap, appxmanifest

I have a problem with publishing my app in windows store. I recive these informations:

> Invalid package identity name: ... (expected: ...
>   ) Invalid package family name:
>   ... (expected:
>   ... ) Invalid package publisher name:
>   weird_numbers_instead_of_my_name (expected:
>   ... )

And I know that this problem was already known and I found an instruction what to do. The problem is that in my case it doesn't work any more. I found this post:

> Thanks for pointing this out. We've deployed a couple of fixes, here's
>   how you should configure your app:
>
> Publisher Name: will be set to what you have set in the
>    field in config.xml Display Name: will be what you
>   have set in the  field in config.xml Package Identity
>   Name: added a new preference: windows-identity-name. retrieve this
>   value from App Management --> App Identity in the Dev Center Package
>   Family Name: will be generated based on the identity name   So as long
>   as you have your Publisher ID set on Build and the following set to
>   the correct values in your config.xm
>   l (sample values below):
>
> ```
> <author>Adobe</author>  
> <name>PhoneGap Build App</name>   
> <preference> name="windows-identity-name" value="PhonegapBuild.PhoneGapBuild" />
> ```
>
> submission should be successful. Let us know if you still see errors.

on this page:https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2111557#
I sticked to the instructions and it helped partly. Now I recieve this communiques:

> Invalid package family name: ...
>   (expected: ...) Invalid package
>   publisher name: weird_numbers_instead_of_my_name (expected:
>   ...)

So I replaced my name in `<author>` with these 'expected' weird_numbers_instead_of_my_name. Then I recived a communique

> Package acceptance validation error: The PublisherDisplayName element
>   in the app manifest of (...).appx is
>   weird_numbers_instead_of_my_name, which doesn't match your publisher display name: my_name_that_i_gave_during_the_registration_process.

So I changed again weird_numbers_instead_of_my_name to my real name which is of course the same as my_name_that_i_gave_during_the_registration_process. And then I recived again:

> Invalid package family name: ... (expected: ...) Invalid package
>   publisher name: weird_numbers_instead_of_my_name (expected: ...)

So I'm wondering if this way given by this guy does't work any more (phonegap needs an update) or windows store works in a different way than before  (phonegap needs an update). Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179436/invalid-package-family-name-error-on-windows-phonegap-app